# Create 2534 new columns in a dataframe based on the median values in the existing 2534 columns

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a dataframe (df) similar to the one mentioned below:

| PATID | Gene1 | Gene2 | Gene3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5.899 | 67.87 | 9.87 |
| 1002 | 6.899 | 60.87 | 10.87 |
| 1003 | 7.899 | 63.87 | 8.87 |

I need a dataframe as mentioned below by looping through the code

`Gene1_med = df['Gene1'].map(lambda exp: 'low' if exp <= df['Gene1'].median() else 'high')`

| PATID | Gene1 | Gene1_med | Gene2 | Gene2_med | Gene3 | Gene3_med |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5.899 | low | 67.87 | high | 9.87 | high |
| 1002 | 6.899 | low | 60.87 | low | 10.87 | high |
| 1003 | 7.899 | high | 63.87 | low | 8.87 | low |

I am new to python and any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with selecting columns of `Gene`s, compare by [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) and assign changed columns names, last sorting columns:

```
cols = ['Gene1','Gene2','Gene3']

#columns PATID to index
df = df.set_index('PATID')

df[pd.Index(cols) + '_med'] = np.where(df[cols].le(df[cols].median()), 'low','high')

df1 = df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Or select all columns with substring `Gene` by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), last sorting all columns without first and append to first column:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Gene')

df[df1.columns + '_med'] = np.where(df1.le(df1.median()), 'low','high')

df1 = df.iloc[:, :1].join(df.iloc[:, 1:].sort_index(axis=1))
```

Or use list for columns names:

```
cols = ['Gene1','Gene2','Gene3']

df[pd.Index(cols) + '_med'] = np.where(df[cols].le(df[cols].median()), 'low','high')

df1 = df.iloc[:, :1].join(df.iloc[:, 1:].sort_index(axis=1))
```

---

```
print (df1)

   PATID  Gene1 Gene1_med  Gene2 Gene2_med  Gene3 Gene3_med
0   1001  5.899       low  67.87      high   9.87       low
1   1002  6.899       low  60.87       low  10.87      high
2   1003  7.899      high  63.87       low   8.87       low
```